# R shiny bookmark button

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

I try to change the text on the pop-up of the bookmarkbutton (other language), but i could not figure out how to do this? Does anyone have a clue:

```
library(shiny)
enableBookmarking(store = "url")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("test", label = "option", choices = c("opt A", "opt B"))
  , bookmarkButton(label = "")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[Change the text in the red rounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy0FI.png)

Comment: I believe those values are hardcoded, see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/shiny/src/R/bookmark-state.R#sym-urlModal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @Tschösi these values are hard coded in the function, which leaves you with 2 options:

1. You create an own copy of the function, where you replace the hard coded versions.
2. You apply some Javascript to change the text dynamically.

Personally, I'd favor option 2.

Here's a working example of how to do that:

```
library(shiny)
js <- HTML(paste("$(function() {",
                 "$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {",
                 "$('.modal-dialog .modal-header > .modal-title').text('Speicher Lesezeichen')", 
                 "$('.modal-dialog .modal-body > span:first').text('Dieser Link speichert den aktuellen Status der Applikation.')",
                 "$('#shiny-bookmark-copy-text').text('Drücken Sie Ctrl-C um den Link zu kopieren.')",
                 "$('.modal-dialog .modal-footer > button').text('Schließen')",
                 "})",
                 "})",
                sep = "\n"))
ui <- function(request) {
   fluidPage(
      tags$head(tags$script(js, type = "text/javascript")),
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("One",
                           checkboxInput("chk1", "Checkbox 1"),
                           bookmarkButton(id = "bookmark1")
                  ),
                  tabPanel("Two",
                           checkboxInput("chk2", "Checkbox 2"),
                           bookmarkButton(id = "bookmark2")
                  )
      )
   )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   # Need to exclude the buttons from themselves being bookmarked
   setBookmarkExclude(c("bookmark1", "bookmark2"))
   
   # Trigger bookmarking with either button
   observeEvent(input$bookmark1, {
      session$doBookmark()
   })
   observeEvent(input$bookmark2, {
      session$doBookmark()
   })
}
enableBookmarking(store = "url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Modal with changed text]

Comment: Thanks! I agree with option 2. 
One minor issue, this will be implemented in a shiny app with multiple other modals. Let's see if it still works :)

Comment: In this case you will need to adapt your jquery selectors in this example to target the proper modal ideally in the selector for the event handler which changes the text. Modals (as implemented in Shiny) are typically dynamically added to the DOM and removed upon closure. That is there should only be one modal at a time. But, of course you do not want the listener to fire the listener with the wrong modal, so adapt the event listener target css to target only modals for which you want to change the text.

Comment: Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Using thothal suggestion, the issue is solved:

```
library(shiny)
enableBookmarking(store = "url")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs()
  , tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "bookmark_vertaling.js")
  )
  , selectInput("test", label = "option", choices = c("opt A", "opt B"))
  , bookmarkButton(label = "", onclick = JS("bookmark_vertaling()"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

with this js-script named "bookmark_vertaling.js" in the www-directory:

```
function bookmark_vertaling() {
  $('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.modal-dialog .modal-title').text('Rechtstreekse link naar deze pagina.');
    $('.modal-dialog .modal-body > span:first').empty();
    $('#shiny-bookmark-copy-text').text('Kopieer deze link (ctrl-c) om rechtstreeks naar deze pagina te linken.');
    $('.modal-dialog .modal-footer > button').text('Sluiten');
  });
}
```

This js-script is loaded in the dashboard using tags$script (make sure you have this script in the www-directory to make it available in the browser). And this js-function is called when I click on the bookmarkButton (onclick)